# Access a control inherited by the child form in parent form

Tags: delphi

I use Delphi XE3. I have two form, TParentForm and TChildForm. TParentForm contains Button1, and TChildForm is inherited from it.

Then when I operate Button1 in TParentForm, in the following procedure **TParentFrm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject)**, is it operating on the instance of Button1 in ChildForm when I invoke ChildForm.Show and click Button1?

```
type
  TParentFrm = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TChildForm = class(TParentFrm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ParentFrm: TParentFrm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TParentFrm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Caption := '&Test';  // Is it operating on Childform's button1 when I
                               // create and show child form and then click 
                               //"Button2".
end;

Test unit:

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      ChildForm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: You are probably getting confused between types and instances. You have two types, and potentially arbitrary numbers of instances of those types. Your question doesn't make any sense. The button is declared in the parent type and inherited by the child type. There is no button declared by the child type.

Comment: When you like to do form inheritance then you have to separate them in different units so each can have its corresponding .dfm file

Comment: @DelphiCoder, I merge them so that it is easy to the reader of the quesiton.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have updated the qusetion to clarify it.

Comment: The question still makes no real sense to me. The child type has no button declared. It inherits the button from the parent type.

Comment: @alancc Could you clarify what you mean by "operating on the instance of"? Is your question "To what instance do Sender point?" Or "What instance do Self point?". You could use ClassName and Name properties in a ShowMessage to learn that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, So my question is, when a child form is created, and click an inherited  button, and the hanlder of that button click event access another button, is the latter button belongs to the parent, or the child?

Comment: @fpiette, TParentFrm.Button2Click has the codeline "Button1.Caption := '&Test'", so my question is this instance of "Button1" blongs to ChildForm?

Comment: I'm not sure that you really appreciate the difference between a type and an instance. Are you aware that you can create multiple instances of your `TParentForm` and `TChildForm`? I'm pretty sure that this understanding is key for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:
Your code will change caption of the Button1 control that is on same form instance that the Button2 that you clicked on.

---

Long answer:
When you use code `Button1.Caption := '&Test';` you basically instructs compute to go and find component named `Button1` and change its `Caption` property to `&Test`. When computer performs this search it always does this within the instance of the form from which the code was called for.

So if your code is called from OnClick event that was fired by button that is placed on your `ParentForm` it will affect the `Button1` that is on your `ParentForm`.

If the code is called from OnClick event that was fired from a button on your `ChildForm` it will affect the `Bu8tton1` that is on your child form.

Yes at this point your application have two buttons named `Button1`. One is on your `ParentForm` and another is on your `ChildForm`

In fact you can also create another instance of your `ParentForm` and clicking on `Button2` on that form will affect the `Button1` on that instance of the form and not the original instance of your `ParentForm`.

I hope my explanation is understandable enough. If not do let me know.

Comment: I'd phrase the long answer slightly differently. `Button1.Caption`, in a method of a (form, in this case) class, means `Self.Button1.Caption`, where `Self` is the hidden parameter that points to the instance (recall: method = code + data). So `Self.Button1` is nothing but the field `Button1` in the object `Self`; you can see its declaration at the top of your form class. So there isn't really much "go and find" necessary; you just dereference a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`TChildForm` inherit from `TParentForm`. Any member of `TParentForm` - not strictly private - are inherited and accessible from `TChildForm` instance. When you create an instance of `TChildForm`, it has Button1 instance inherited from his parent class, that is `TParentForm`.

Do not confuse a type (the definition of a class) and an instance (for short: the data allocated at runtime).

If you create two instances of `TChildForm` (calling the constructor), you have two distinct instances of button1 and button2 as well. Button2 `OnClick` handler of one instance will act of button1 instance in the same `TChildForm` instance as itself.

In my opinion, you should stay away from form inheritance before fully understanding the general mechanism behind inheritance.